# AWS SageMaker (with internet disabled) unable to connect to STS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc, amazon-sagemaker

I am unable to perform the simple action:

```
import sagemaker
sess = sagemaker.Session()
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
```

because my notebook instance is not connected to the internet. I have an STS endpoint interface in the same subnet as my notebook instance but I thought the sagemaker API is using the global endpoint. I actually get the following error message after a while:

```
ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

How do I fix this? Or does one need to update the sagemaker module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to include a VPC endpoint for the sagemaker API (api.sagemaker...) as well as STS.